# Spring boot transaction for non transactional db operations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-transactions

I have a function that performs a combination of database and non-database operations.
The point is that we are using a non-transactional database (Cassandra database).
I need the operations inside this function to be done as a transaction. Definitely @Transactional annotation can not be used.
What do you suggest to solve this problem?

```
@Transactional
public Definition save(Request request){
  redis.getAndDelete(request.getDefinition().getId());
  Container.increment();
  Definition savedDefinition = CassandraDefinitionCallBack.insert(request.getDefinition());
  return savedDefinition;
}
```

Comment: What would you want to do in case of a transaction failure if the database doesn't support transactions? Deleting inserted elements is fairly easy to achieve but how about updates and deletes? And how about the lack of isolation, i.e. writes being visible right after the DB call? All of this is solvable to some extend and with some effort but might depend on your requirements and environment. One pattern you could look up to achieve this would be the Saga pattern. However, you'd still need to know what compensations should look like.